# Connecting to Excel ODBC

Tags: sql-server, excel, odbc

I have the below query and I was wondering how to setup an ODBC connection to get this to an excel spreadsheet.

```
declare @StartDate DATE
declare @EndDate   DATE

SELECT Sum(case when status = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as Failed,
   Sum(case when status = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as Successful,
   UniqueID
Into #tempsheet1
FROM Documents
WHERE ownerID = 467
and status in (6,9)
and CreationTime between @StartDate and @EndDate
Group By UniqueID

Select D.UniqueID, FromName, ToName, CreationTime,
cast(CreationTime as date) as CreationDate, cast(CreationTime as date) as CreationTime,
ErrorCode, ElapsedSendTime, RemoteID
From #tempsheet1 ts1
Inner Join Documents D On
D.UniqueID = ts1.UniqueID
and [Status] = 9

ORDER BY D.CreationTime desc
```

I'm still researching stuff online, but if anyone can point me in the right direction or give me some tips that would be awesome.

Comment: That's invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What do you mean it's invalid?  It is running fine.  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I said it's invalid **standard** SQL

Answer (score 0):

In excel go to Data tab > Get external data > From other sources > From Microsoft Query. From there depends on what type of database you are connecting to but the wizard should guide you through.

Once you have your connection set you can right click in the resulting data set and select table > edit query, choose command type = SQL and then edit your query as required.

Depending on what you are doing an ADO db connection may be better and will allow you to set dynamic date filters and the like... but that is another topic

Edit: ADO approach below

1. Add a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data objects library
2. Figure out your connection string: https://www.connectionstrings.com/
3. Implement something like the below

.

```
Sub adoConExample()

    Dim startDate As String
    Dim endDate As String
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String

    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    startDate = format("Your date range reference".value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    endDate = format("Your date range reference".value, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    With con
        .ConnectionString = "Your connection string"
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open
    End With

    sql = "Your sql string"
    sql = Replace(sql, "DATE1", startDate)
    sql = Replace(sql, "DATE2", endDate)

    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open sql, con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

    "Your paste target range".CopyFromRecordset rs

    con.Close
    rs = Nothing
    con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: If you use Microsoft Query, you are able to have dynamic dates

Comment: I just need for the user to be able to input dates ranges into one or two cells in SQL (A1 or A1 and B1 for example) and for the data to automatically update according to the user input.

Comment: I dont know how to do this with Gregory's approach. You can use the ADO approach edit above but if its possible with ODBC that would seem much simpler in your case